# Can't find Google OAuth API in Developer console

Tags: google-oauth

I am implementing `Login with Google` using OAuth API but I can't find it to enable it on Google Developer console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to enable `Google+ API` to implement Google OAuth in application.

Comment: thank god i was freaked out that google might removed that feature. i was a little bit away from these things lately. thanks man